# Java adding JLabels to Panel embedded in ScrollPane

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel, scrollpane

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setBounds(23, 11, 603, 123);

contentPane.add(scrollPane);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel[] labels=new JLabel[callout.getRedCount()]; //callout.getRedCount() = 8
panel.setLayout(null);
int x = 50;
int y = 50;
for (int i=0;i<callout.getRedCount();i++){ //callout.getRedCount() = 8
        labels[i]=new JLabel("Red" + i);
        labels[i].setBounds(x, y, 32, 32);
        panel.add(labels[i]);
        x += 150;
}
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
```

I'm  trying to add these labels to the panel that is embedded in a `scrollPane`. The labels are display correctly except for when the last few are over the size of the panel. The `scrollPane` does not scroll. I have tried `.setLayout` to various different layouts and still no results. Am I missing something on how to do this?

Comment: Does the scroll pane display the proper width of the panel? I.E. is the scrollbar showing that it is possible to move horizontally, but wont?

Comment: Because I have `.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` it displays the arrows on either side, but there is no scroll bar. I can make my labels display where one will be cut off half way from the scrollpane and it still does not scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got this working with GridBagLayout.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    JFrame contentPane = new JFrame();

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(23, 11, 50, 50);

    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel[] labels=new JLabel[8]; //callout.getRedCount() = 8
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,0);
    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){ //callout.getRedCount() = 8
            labels[i]=new JLabel("Red" + i);
            gbc.gridx = i;
            panel.add(labels[i], gbc);
    }
    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    contentPane.setSize(50,50);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);

}
```

You can change around the values, this is *very rough*. Hope this helps!

Comment: Genius! I'll research GridBagLayout because I need 3 panels on top of each other inside a scrollPane. Kind of like columns and tables. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! There is a lot of support for GridBagLayout on here, so more often than not you can find a solution to your GridBagLayout problems with a quick google search!